# How to estimate mining fee for raw transaction?

Tags: bitcoind, mining-reward, createrawtransaction

In our application we are generating a trasaction hex using the `createrawtransaction` call to "handcraft" a transaction. The problem we are facing is that we would like to estimate the mining fee for this transaction. I realize that we could call `estimatefee x` to estimate the mining fee per byte. But the problem is we are generating the transaction, so we don't know the size of the transaction yet! Chicken or egg?! I realize that we can generate a transaction and then account for the mining fee based on the hex, but this sounds like a hack to me.

So the question is: what's the best way to estimate the optimal mining fee while using `createrawtransaction` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `fundrawtransaction` (if you are okay using the internal wallet).
`fundrawtransaction` will give you back the used `fee` (next to the hex byte-array of the funded transaction) before signing or broadcasting the transaction.

### The ideal workflow is:

- `createrawtransaction '[]' '{"<addr>": <amount>}' //set no inputs`
- `fundrawtransaction <hex>`
- you'll get back `{"hex":<tx>, "fee": <amount>, "changepos": <pos of the change output>}`
- Check the fee, maybe increase it (requires Bitcoin Core 0.14, use the `feeRate` of `fundrawtransaction`.
- `signrawtransaction <hex>`
- `sendrawtransaction <hex>`

Comment: This is a great suggestion! But we want to spend from a particular address in the wallet which we retrieve from `listunspent` .. so it won't work for us as there is no way to do this filtering in `fundrawtransaction`

Comment: In that case you need to calculate the transaction size by yourself by assume 72byte per EC sig. But it depends what types of inputs you support (P2PKH, etc.).

Comment: Well they are all multisig addresses .. So P2SH